# Split all tiff pages using Libtiff

Tags: c#, libtiff.net

Using LibTiff, following will get the 2nd page and save as SplitTiffImage_2ndPage.tif.

```
string[] arguments =
{
  @"Sample Data\multipage.tif,1",
  "SplitTiffImage_2ndPage.tif"
};
TiffCP.Program.Main(arguments);
```

How to split all the pages in a multipage tif? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [this example](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/extract-a-page-from-a-multi-page-tiff-image.aspx). On the same site you can find [an example](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/retrieve-number-of-pages-in-tiff-image.aspx) how to get the number of pages of a tiff. You can combine the two examples to extract all pages by looping from `0` to `num_of_pages - 1` with a simple for loop and build the appropriate two strings and with these two strings the argument array for `TiffCP.Program.Main` for every index.

First page -> `string[] arguments = {@"Sample Data\multipage.tif,0", "SplitTiffImage_Page1.tif"`

Second page -> `string[] arguments = {@"Sample Data\multipage.tif,1", "SplitTiffImage_Page2.tif"`

and so on...